# Retract of a chain complex.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $A_*$ and $B_*$ be projective chain complexes which are zero in dimensions $i=-1$ and down. Now suppose there exist maps $A_* \xrightarrow i B_* \xrightarrow r A_*$ such that $r \circ i = \text{id}_A$ and such that $i$ is a cofibration and $r$ is a fibration using the projective model structure.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes#CochainNonNeg

What can we say about the homology of $A_*$ and $B_*$? Are they isomorphic? If not, can we at least say that if $A_*$ is acyclic then $B_*$ is aswell? What bout the other way around, if $B_*$ is acyclic is $A_*$ acyclic aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Such maps $i,r$ imply (in any abelian category) that $B_*\cong A_*\oplus \ker(r)$ so that the homology of $B_*$ is the direct sum of that of $A_*$ and that of $\ker(r)$.

In particular if $B_*$ is acyclic, so is $A_*$, but you can't say much more ($\ker(r)$ can be as weird as you want) : this has nothing to do with model structures or projectives.